# making elements stack left not below

Tags: css

i am not able to explain it correctly....but here it is....i want DIVs to float left in the container such that...when their total width increases the width of the container...they will make a horizontal scroll-bar but will not go below one another in any case...
like if the container's width is 500px;
and it contains 5 children DIVs each of 200px width
now when i float then left...they stack like 2 in a row and 2 in the next row....eg:
div1 div2
div3 div4
div5
i want them something like this :
div1 div2 div3 div4 div5
with scroll-bar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend, instead of floating them, set `display:inline-block;`, then apply `white-space:nowrap` to the container element.

And be sure the container has no fixed width. (min-width is OK though).

**update** 
1) fixed error (thanks to JOPLOmacedo)
2) working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/t9Vnf/

Comment: `

#handler {
 position: absolute;
 height: 225px;
 white-space: no-wrap;
 left:0px;
}

#handler .item{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 10px;
}`

Comment: This is probably the best solution. The reason you can't see it working is because it should be `white-space: nowrap;` rather than `white-space: nowrap;`. There's an extra hypen in there. Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/cquQB/3/

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo: thanks for catching that. I've updated the post, a

Comment: hey but now there's a new problem...see this -http://jsfiddle.net/t9Vnf/1/ ..now the text inside the children divs is overflowing..instead of goin to next line....